# Find most recent file and copy to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, date, copy

I'm trying to combine these two macros:

Macro 1: This finds a file and copies the sheet to another workbook. I need to find the latest file with the prefix "Car Assignments", this only works if I manually type the full file name.

```vb
Sub cpy()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    
    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("\\Desktop\ARC Dev\New folder\Car Assignments 11-16-2020.xlsx")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("\\Desktop\ARC Dev\arcgoat.xlsm")
    
    'Now, copy what you want from x:
    x.Sheets("Portfolio Assignments").Range("A1:U920").Copy
    
    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    y.Sheets("Portfolio Assignments").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    
    'Close x:
    x.Close
    MsgBox ("Completed")
End Sub
```

Macro 2: This finds the most recent file in the directory, however, it does not account for files with the prefix 'Car Assignments'.

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub NewestFile()
    
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
        
    MyPath = "\\Desktop\ARC Dev\New folder\"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
    
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
    
End Sub
```

I am trying to copy the latest Excel file in "\Desktop\ARC Dev\New folder" directory that has the name "Car Assignments" in it, and then copy that sheet to a workbook called arcgoat in the "\Desktop\ARC Dev\arcgoat.xlsm" directory.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490868/finding-latest-file-in-a-folder-and-opening-it-vba-access) help? That returns a file object, which you can use in a function.

Comment: Thanks for that -- that specific thread actually helped me get the second macro working earlier today. The problem is slightly different though because I'm hoping to find/copy the sheet from the most recent file with the prefix "Car Assignments", not just most recent xlsx in the overall directory if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code as you like ,

```
Sub NewestFile()

Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date
Dim x As Workbook 'content copied to this work book
Dim y As Workbook 'y latest work book,where the content copied from

Set x = ActiveWorkbook

'MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\files\" ' x workbook_location/files - Search the latest file y  here

MyPath = "C:\Users\siddharth\Desktop\ARC Dev\New folder\" 'search the y workbook here

If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "Car Assignments*.xlsx", vbNormal)

If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub

End If

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Set y = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)
y.Sheets("Portfolio Assignments").Range("A1:U920").Copy

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Error msg pop disable
x.Sheets("Portfolio Assignments").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

y.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' Error msg enabled back

MsgBox ("Content Copied")

End Sub
```

Comment: So I ran your script and it's prompting the no files were found message.  The directory in which the latest Car Assignments files are located is \\Desktop\ARC Dev\New folder\    -- Maybe i don't understand VBA well enough, but I don't see where that directory is specified to know where to look for the latest files?  Also the file in which we are pasting the data we copy is :  "\\Desktop\ARC Dev\arcgoat.xlsm"  in the sheet called "Portfolio Assignments"

Comment: Code is updated , check it. and Mention full path name in Mypath @Amateurhour35